# In Python3 display true if search term is in CSV table

Tags: database, python-3.x, csv, input, pycharm

I want a user to be able to search for a specific term and if it is in the database a message will be given saying that it is in the database.

This is the code that I have made so far and it runs without errors, but when I enter a search term it always says "We are sorry, but that does not seem to be in our system" and it always says this 3 times. I am using Pycharm as my IDE, but I don't think that this should make a difference.

I am semi new to Python so please be patient with me if I have missed something simple : )

```
    import csv

    uIn = input("Please enter a search term: ")

    with open('database.csv', 'r') as uFile:
        fileReader = csv.reader(uFile, delimiter=',')
        for row in fileReader:
            if uIn == row[1]: #True
                print (uIn + "is in file")
            else: #False
                print("We are sorry, but that does not seem to be in our system")
```

----------------------------------------------------------Edit----------------------------------------------------------------

Thank you, @Rahul Bhatnagar, for your answer; it showed me that I needed to switch == with in.

This does answer part of the question, and I have figured out some of the other part, the else statement prints for every row that does not have the uIn inside of it. So say the uIn was on the third row the script would print the #False statement twice and the #True statement once. This is alrightish, but if the uIn is on say the 50th row or the 100th row then there would be 49 or 99 #false statements printed.

I would now say that about 50% of my problem is fixed, the part that is not fixed, is to only print 1 #true or 1 #false statement if it is in the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

def search(uIn):
    found = false;
    with open('database.csv', 'r') as uFile:
        fileReader = csv.reader(uFile, delimiter=',')
        for row in fileReader:
            if uIn in row: #True
                found = true;
    if(found):
        print ("Found the string in file!")
    else:
        print("We are sorry, but that does not seem to be in our system")


uIn = raw_input("ST: ")
search(uIn)
```

Where my database.csv file is :

```
search,terms,go,into,this,file,in,this,format
```

You're trying to find uIn at position 1 of row in all cases, which is not going to be the situation.

Comment: Your answer has helped me some, I actually need it to only be in position1 as the other positions are information that the user does not need to see. When looking over what you posted why it was not showing up for me is that I put                                                               if uIn == row: instead of if uIn in row:

Comment: I've made some edits to my answer, that should complete the problem.